# epublib android

Tags: android, epub, epublib

I see the Link http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android But I can't download epub-core lib.jar 
and in this link Under Getting Start they mention to compile using the "mvn package" what that means?

Answer (score 1):

Github cloud does seem to run into [some or the other trouble](https://github.com/kballard/Newzbin-SABnzbd.safariextz/issues/1) with the way in which the URL is encoded. 
Your issue might also be related to that. You'd be better off posting to github's support forum - they're usually quick with their responses.

As for `Maven` package - well, you'll need to [download and install maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) and use it from your terminal/dos to create a JAR from the source. Maven is build tool used in Java applications/libraries.

Comment: Ok Thanks But can you tell me i am try to compile but i fail  can i see right link or not

   1.  See http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/download for details
   2. Compile epublib
      Compile with maven by doing ‘mvn package’.
      Download maven from http://maven.apache.org/ if necessary.
   3. Add epublib to your project
      Add epublib-core/target/epublib-core-<VERSION>.jar to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add slf4j-api and slf4j-simple for the http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android as they are dependencies for slf4j-android and made them available to build path.